# Read committed Isolation Level in postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core

I tried to insert and read the values from same table using readcommitted isolation level with in the same transaction.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html from this document I came to know read comitted isolation level will read the uncommitted changes with in the same transaction. But I am not able to read the uncommitted values. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong!

Comment: That mrans that you are in a different transaction.

Comment: What did you try? What does the *actual* code look like? The *same* transaction can see all changes made by it. Different transactions can't

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql, in open transactions, you can read any value inserted/updated by the same transaction. transaction isolation is a construct that defines the isolation at the transaction level inside the transaction stored procedure can read any value it inserted/updated even if it is not committed and regardless of isolation level.